# Installing MariaDB 10.4 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, repository, mariadb

I am experiencing some trouble with installing MariaDB 10.4 on Centos 7. The official [mariaDB guide](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos7-ppc64le--centos7&mirror=rackspace&version=10.4) says that a new repo file `MariaDB.repo` should created in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` with the contents of:

```
# MariaDB 10.4 CentOS repository list - created 2019-12-13 22:03 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-ppc64le
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

I've run `yum-config-manager --enable  MariaDB.repo` and `yum update` and inspected the enabled repos:

```
$ enabled | grep maria
mariadb          MariaDB              86
```

This confirms that the new repo is enabled. The guide later says to run `sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`. Unfortunately, there is nothing to install as I am greeted with a message:

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.anexia.at
 * epel: ftp.uni-kl.de
 * extras: mirror.easyname.at
 * remi-php74: remi.mirror.karneval.cz
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.karneval.cz
 * updates: centos.anexia.at
No package MariaDB-server available.
  * Maybe you meant: mariadb-server
No package MariaDB-client available.
```

Notice that there is no mention of `MariaDB.repo` I just enabled. Also, the suggested package `mariadb-server` is version 5.5. What is the correct way to install MariaDB version 10.4 on Centos 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have selected the wrong cpu architecture in the MariaDB Repository Configuration Tool.

I've tested in a CentOS 7 with Intel cpu and with the MariaDB.repo that you post behaves as you say, but if I configure the repo for Intel (x86_64) installs correctly when I execute

```
yum install MariaDB-server
```

The output is

```
# yum install MariaDB-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.uvigo.es
 * extras: centos.uvigo.es
 * updates: centos.uvigo.es
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.4.11-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                     Arch                                Version                                            Repository                            Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 MariaDB-server                              x86_64                              10.4.11-1.el7.centos                               mariadb                               26 M
```

If the cpu selection is correct I don't known what could be happening and I don't have a system with ppc64le architecture to test.

Answer (score 1):

```
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-ppc64le
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ppc64

In simple words, it is wrong CPU architecture, if you use PC but not IBM hardware.
I guess you want x86_64 / amd64, so check http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64/